# Deserialization taking time in Xamarin iOS Application

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am facing an  issue while desializing a file from Xamarin ios.
I am using **Proto-Buf** method for Serialize and desterilize operations.
Deserialization takes over 25 second in iPad 2, and around 8 seconds in iPad Air.
That same deserialization takes only  1 or 2 seconds  in windows application.
The Class having around 95 properties and also having inner classes. Normally list will have 300-500 records.

1. Is there any  Asynchronous way to desrializae the file? So that it will not take time to load the UI grid.
2. Should we need restructure the class and need to save the file as multiple files?
3. Or Should  we need to split line list to sub list’s and save it to separate files?
4. Is there any other better ways?

Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I use [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/). They claim to be the fastest. I'm not sure about that claim, but I find it pretty good. Please let us know your test results if you try it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried JSON.Net? It is cross-platform and works pretty fast. Also, what if you wrap your (de)serialization in a Task and `await` it?

Comment: We have checked the Json.Net  for serialize and deserialize our object. The time taken for Protobuf and json.net  as below
  

Protobuf-Deserialization -- iPad2--25 sec, 
Protobuf-Deserialization -- simulator-- 5 sec,
Json.Net- Deserialization-- iPad2--80 sec,
Json.Net- Deserialization-- simulator-- 9 sec

Dou you have any other suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure how to decrease the time without paging/doing it in batches. Have you at least tried to do it async as to not block the UI thread?